# CentOS Freezes on Startup

Tags: linux, boot, centos, grub

I'm very new to Linux, so please go easy!

I created a Linux install on VMWare Workstation 8 in order to install a piece of software called OpenClinica.  The program is Java based and depends on Apache Tomcat and PostgreSQL.  (installation instructions are here: https://docs.openclinica.com/3.1/installation/installation-linux)

I followed the instructions up to 9.1.16 where I reboot the system.  When the system starts up, the progress indicator goes all the way to the end and freezes. I try rebooting a couple of times but the same thing happens. So, I do some Googling and start the system in single user mode and pull out the log messages:

```
open /dev/fb0: no such device
expected keysim, got XF86TouchPadOn: line 120 of inet
expected keysim, got XF86TouchPadOff: line 121 of inet
Failed to execute message bus daemon /bin/dbus-daemon: permission denied
...
waiting for xserver to shutdown error setting MTTR (base = 0xD0000000, size = 0x02000000, type = 1) invalid argument (22)

/usr/bin/startx: line 197: /usr/bin/xauth: permisison denied
```

I'm at a loss and unsure where to go next with this.  If anyone coul point me in the right direction then it would be much appreciated

Comment: What are the permissions on that file? Try entering `ls -l /usr/bin/xauth`.

Comment: That gives `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43176 aug 18 2010 xauth

Comment: Looking over the instructions, they install their own versions of tomcat and postgres, when CentOS provides perfectly serviceable versions of those. That is a bad symptom in itself. Were you able to run any graphics before mangling the system as the instructions say?

Comment: When you say graphics, do you mean the standard GUI that CentOS provides?  If so, then yes everything was working fine before I followed the installation procedure.  Would I best to create a new VM and try the installation again but omit the tomcat and postgres install?